# Using Rotativa in an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to use a PDF generator in my ASP.NET MVC application. I downloaded a package for rotativa but I am still not able to fix my import. What package do I need to download and install?

I have downloaded the first Rotativa package called "Rotativa" by Giorgio Bozio but it did not allow me to use the Rotativa import.

[Rotativa Packages Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vvx5y.png)

Code:

```
using System.IO;
using Rotativa;      // Rotativa is underlined red in my application
```

Comment: Which framework stay in your project and which required for this lib?

Comment: How are you trying to use? Can you show your code?